# Upload de arquivos com fileinput

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou utilizando o `fileinput` deste site [Bootstrap: fileinput.js v3.1.3](http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput)
e estou precisando de recuperar o `BLOB` da imagem upada ao submeter o formulário.

Observei que ao fazer o `uplod` de alguma imagem a tag `img` aparece e nela é colocado o `BLOB`. Como na imagem a seguir:

[image: Inspecionamento do html cujo código representa meu campo de upload de imagem.]

Meus códigos HTML está da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
 <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
  <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput"><img class="img-responsive" src="{{$igreja->BLO_IMAGM_IGREJ}}" alt=""></div>
   <div>
    <span class="btn btn-info btn-file">
    <span class="fileinput-new">Selecionar foto</span>
    <input type="file" name="...">
    </span>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remover</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

> Pensei em faze da seguinte forma, ao efetuar o upload do arquivo eu setar em um campo com a propriedade hidden o blob da imagem upada, e assim eu consigo recuperar estes dados la no meu controller.

A titulo de curiosidade estou utilizando o `Laravel 5.3`.

Comment: Recuperar o BLOB no backend? Mas isso não é trabalho do proprio fileinput.js enviar para o back-end? Quero dizer, aonde esta falhando? Mostre a parte javascript, como você fez

Comment: A minha parte de js esta junta com api, exatamente isto que quero, quero setar o blob da imagem upada em um campo qualquer.

Comment: Entendi o fileinput não faz upload, ao menos é o que parece, vou tentar ver se é possivel adapta-lo, todavia me parece melhor rever o uso desta lib e pensar em algo mais funcional.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento se tiver algo mais interessante para apresentar que resolva meu problema, estaria muito satisfeito.

Comment: Tem sim, é que estou tentando formular uma resposta que já funcione com Laravel, é que por não usar o Laravel estou tendo que instalar ;) assim que possivel irei responder

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento se quiser colocar so como será feita no front-end, pode ser, pois pegar com laravel para mim é tranquilo, so preciso setar o valor do blob em um campo, so isto